# Debian 8, ошибка XRDP

Tags: linux, debian, xrdp

Поставил Debian 8, все из коробки.
Установил XRDP, пробую коннектиться с винды, вот что он мне показывает ("Oh no! Something has gone wrong.")

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему так?

Log:

```html
[20150612-21:05:19] [CORE ] starting sesman with pid 3194
[20150612-21:05:19] [INFO ] listening...
[20150612-21:08:22] [INFO ] scp thread on sck 7 started successfully
[20150612-21:08:22] [INFO ] ++ created session (access granted): username sanu0074, ip 192.168.1.35:51164 - socket: 7
[20150612-21:08:22] [INFO ] starting Xvnc session...
[20150612-21:08:22] [INFO ] starting xrdp-sessvc - xpid=3244 - wmpid=3243
[20150612-21:10:39] [INFO ] scp thread on sck 7 started successfully
[20150612-21:10:39] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username sanu0074, display :10.0, session_pid 3242, ip 192.168.1.35:52693 - socket: 7
[20150612-21:15:27] [INFO ] scp thread on sck 7 started successfully
[20150612-21:15:44] [INFO ] scp thread on sck 7 started successfully
[20150612-21:15:45] [INFO ] ++ created session (access granted): username sanu0074, ip 192.168.1.35:56634 - socket: 7
[20150612-21:15:45] [INFO ] starting Xvnc session...
[20150612-21:15:45] [INFO ] starting xrdp-sessvc - xpid=3478 - wmpid=3477
[20150612-21:18:05] [INFO ] shutting down sesman 1
[20150612-21:18:05] [CORE ] starting sesman with pid 5117
[20150612-21:18:05] [INFO ] listening...
[20150612-21:19:17] [INFO ] scp thread on sck 7 started successfully
[20150612-21:19:37] [INFO ] scp thread on sck 7 started successfully
[20150612-21:19:37] [INFO ] ++ created session (access granted): username sanu0074, ip 192.168.1.35:58717 - socket: 7
[20150612-21:19:37] [INFO ] starting Xvnc session...
[20150612-21:19:37] [INFO ] starting xrdp-sessvc - xpid=5139 - wmpid=5138
[20150612-21:53:47] [INFO ] shutting down sesman 1
[20150612-22:12:24] [CORE ] starting sesman with pid 26889
[20150612-22:12:24] [INFO ] listening...
[20150612-22:12:47] [INFO ] shutting down sesman 1
[20150612-22:53:25] [CORE ] starting sesman with pid 31801
[20150612-22:53:25] [INFO ] listening...
[20150612-22:57:22] [INFO ] scp thread on sck 7 started successfully
[20150612-22:57:22] [INFO ] ++ created session (access granted): username sanu0074, ip 192.168.1.35:50614 - socket: 7
[20150612-22:57:22] [INFO ] starting Xvnc session...
[20150612-22:57:23] [INFO ] starting xrdp-sessvc - xpid=32031 - wmpid=32030
[20150612-23:03:30] [INFO ] ++ terminated session:  username sanu0074, display :13.0, session_pid 32029, ip 192.168.1.35:50614 - socket: 7
[20150612-23:03:30] [INFO ] shutting down sesman 1
[20150613-00:01:07] [CORE ] starting sesman with pid 666
[20150613-00:01:07] [INFO ] listening...
[20150613-00:01:55] [CORE ] starting sesman with pid 596
[20150613-00:01:55] [INFO ] listening...
[20150613-00:05:49] [CORE ] starting sesman with pid 569
[20150613-00:05:49] [INFO ] listening...
```

Comment: Мы не можем просто так, по скриншоту, определенно сказать, в чем проблема. Приведите хотя бы логи и настройки и убедитесь, что нужные сервисы запущены.

Comment: сорри, прицепил лог